# Filter GridView populated with EntityDataSource by where

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a GridView that uses a EntityDataSource.
In this GridView there is a column that contains some foreign keys (ID's).
I get the ID I want to display as a parameter in the website ("Details.aspx?id=1").
How do i get the parameter from the URL in the Where Expression of the EntityDataSource?

The parameter source dropdown displays these sources : Cookie, Control, Form, Profile, QueryString, Session, RouteData. Which one do I need to use to get the id from the url?

So far I created the entire webpage using just the interface (didn't write any cod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `entitydatasource` supports a `querystringparameter` object.

From the designer you can specify it.

Or you could do declaratively in the aspx.

```
<WhereParameters>
     <asp:QueryStringParameter DbType="Int32" Name="id" QueryStringField="id" />
  </WhereParameters>
```